# How to get the follow integration formula by substitution

Tags: integration

I have a formula of pdf:
$$f_W (w) = \left( \frac{1}{\mu} \right) \int_{u = 0}^1 \left( \frac{w}{u^2}
\right) f_m (w / u) d u$$
How to get the follow integration formula by substitution $y=(w/u)$
$$f_W (w) = \left( \frac{1}{\mu} \right) \int_{y = w}^{\infty} f_m (y) d y$$

Comment: $y = \frac wu \Rightarrow \frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dy} = -\frac w{y^2}$ the $-$ cancels with swapping the integration bounds

Answer (score 1):

Just perform the substitution:
$$y = \frac wu \Rightarrow \frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dy} = -\frac w{y^2}$$
and $u = 1 \Rightarrow y = w, u \to 0 \Rightarrow y \to \infty$. This gives
$$f_W(w) = \frac1\mu \int_{\infty}^w \frac{w y^2}{w^2} f_m(y) \cdot -\frac w{y^2} \;\mathrm dy = -\frac1\mu \int_{\infty}^w \frac{y^2}w \cdot \frac w{y^2} f_m(y)\;\mathrm dy = \frac1\mu \int_w^\infty f_m(y)\;\mathrm dy$$
as claimed.

Answer (score 1):

$$y=\frac wu\implies dy=-\frac w{u^2}du\implies du=-\frac{u^2}wdy=-0\frac{w^2}{y^2w}dy=-\frac w{y^2}dy$$

Integral's limits:

$$y=\frac wu\;\;:\;\;\;\begin{cases}u=0\implies y=\infty\;\text{(assuming}\;w>0)\\{}\\u=1\implies y=w\end{cases}$$

Thus, the integral becomes

$$f_W(w)=\frac1\mu\int_\infty^w\left(\frac{y^2}w\right) f_m(y)\left(-\frac w{y^2}dy\right)=\frac 1\mu\int_w^\infty f_m(y)\;dy$$